Adding custom filters with mkdocs-simple-hooks
I'm using MkDocs and I want to add a custom filter. Based on this answer, I'm using mkdocs-simple-hooks. The answer suggests using the on_env event to add custom filters to the Jinja2 environment. Here's what my structure looks like:
/
|__ docs/
|   |__ data/my_data.csv
|   |__ modules/hooks.py
|   |__ my_doc.md
|
|__ templates/my_template.html
|
|__ mkdocs.yml

My mkdocs.yml config file looks like this:
plugins:
  - search
  - mkdocs-simple-hooks:
      hooks:
        on_env: "docs.modules.hooks:on_env"
theme:
  name: material
  custom_dir: templates

The docs/modules/hooks.py looks like this:
import pandas
def csv_to_html(csv_path):
    return pandas.read_csv(csv_path).to_html()

def on_env(env, config, **kwargs):
    env.filters['csv_to_html'] = csv_to_html
    return env

The templates/my_template.html looks like this:
<div>
{{ csv_to_html("data/my_data.csv") }}
</div>

I'm expecting the csv_to_html filter to be made available during the on_env event so that the Jinja2 environment in my_template.html can use it, but when I run mkdocs build I recieve this error:
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'csv_to_html' is undefined

What am I doing wrong? How do I correctly add custom filters in MkDocs?
